# What is the best way to enter multiple conditionals into excel?

Tags: excel

I'm writing an excel spreadsheet that will allow for quick comparison between values different users get against expected values.

I don't care about specific comparisons beyond any differences at all between expected results and actual results. However, I also want to make it easier on everyone by allowing them to only enter values if they're different than the expected results.

So I have a table set up sort of like this:

```
|            |  Expected Results  |     Name 1    |     Name 2    |     Name 3    | Differences? |
|------------|----------|---------|--------|------|--------|------|--------|------|--------------|
|            | Pass     | Fail    | Pass   | Fail | Pass   | Fail | Pass   | Fail |              |
| Category 1 | 10       | 10      |        |      |        |      |        |      | No           |
| Category 2 | 20       | 15      | 19     | 16   |        |      |        | 16   | Yes          |
| Category 3 | 5        | 10      | 10     | 5    | 5      | 10   |        | 6    | Yes          |
```

I came up with the following formula which would work with everyone putting in all their results, but it won't work if someone doesn't enter data due to it matching up with the expected values.

```
=IF(AND(A3=F3,A3=J3,A3=N3,A3=R3,C3=G3,C3=K3,C3=O3,C3=S3,D3=H3,D3=L3,D3=P3,D3=T3,E3=I3,E3=M3,E3=Q3,E3=U3),"NO","YES")
```

Comment: This is kind of unclear. What is the value of `A3`? What are you comparing?

Comment: So you're saying: if A value equals F, J, N and R value, C value equals G, K, O and S value, D value equals H, L, P and T value and E value equals I, M, Q and U value, then you should have "No", else you should have "Yes". Something like that? (It's difficult to understand while seeing the table without the column heading letters)

Answer (score 1):

You have the new function [IFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45)
This function allows you to enter many conditions and many creteria's:

Generally, the syntax for the IFS function is:

```
=IFS([Something is True1, Value if True1,Something is True2,Value if True2,Something is True3,Value if True3)
```